# Have align environment use only needed width

Tags: tables, align, amsmath

I'm using `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` inside a `tabular` table. However, the spacing inconsistent because the align environment uses more width than the equation needs. Is there a way to have the align environment take only the space occupied by its content?

Comment: use `aligned` not `align`, `align` is always full width of the current text block.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! The horizontal spacing is correct now. However, the vertical spacing is incorrect now. The table row is now vertically centered rather than top-aligned and there is no vertical cell padding even though I'm using `\def\arraystretch{2}`. These are `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{10em}` columns.

Comment: `\begin{aligned}[t]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot, the spacing is perfect now. If you'd like to write a short answer with this command I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inline math with a nested `aligned`

```
...& $\begin{aligned}[t] a&b... \end{aligned}$ ...
```